# Escape " " in Text in TextView

Tags: android

I have a textView and I am pasting s string as it's text and in which I have some "double quote characters" How can I escape these characters.

Comment: You want add those qoutes or remove those quotes before adding string to textview?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Backslashing double quotes will not work in a XML layout. You should use the HTML-code (*quot*), like this:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Here goes my &quot;escaped&quot; text!" />
```

The above code will display a TextView containing:

> Here goes my "escaped" text!

XML has [5 of these predifined entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML):

```
&quot;   "
&amp;    &
&apos;   '
&lt;     <
&gt;     >
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the replace method of the String class: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)

Use something like this for you String and then pass this String to the TextView:

```
myString.replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: I have to paste it in the xml, there i have to escape them. I was not able to paste it, it will give an error saying TextView is not closed.